# MySQL select times of day independent of date

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have the below records what i want to do is select the records based on their time of day independent of month, year or day. 
In short " select all records between 12:00 and 14:00" and it should return me A and D. How can I do that?

```
A 2012-10-24 12:00:00
B 2012-13-25 03:00:00
C 2012-12-25 20:00:00
D 2012-16-26 14:00:00
```

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE HOUR(date) BETWEEN 12 AND 14
```

read more about this function [here(w3 resource)](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-hour-function.php)

If you want based on hour and minute, then you need [TIME()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) function.

syntax : `WHERE TIME(datetime) >= '18:00:00'`

Comment: If i want to give hour and minutes? ex. 12:30 - 2:30? how would i do that?